# Weird arrow icon next to Apple logo

Tags: macos

I am seeing this weird arrow icon next to Apple icon in OSX Mavericks. No idea what it is. The z-index is higher than the mouse pointer. (If I hover mouse pointer there, it goes behind the arrow).

I tried to take it's screenshot but it was not there. I took a picture using my phone.

Anyone has any idea?

[image]

Comment: Well, that's weird. What happens if you click on it? How about right-click?

Comment: No interaction are working. Maybe I should restart. Lol

Comment: Restarting made the arrow symbol disappear. I am still curious what it was though.

Comment: Were you running any new piece of software, which perhaps had a bug that placed that as a floating image? Other than that, I got nuthin'. (And it's probably not worth a lot of worry.)

Comment: Sure is a fun puzzler.  Did it ever come back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like one of the arrow cursors for when you hover over certain parts of the screen (resizing?). Sometimes the cursor gets stuck on certain parts of the screen. Even though I can still move my mouse, a copy of the cursor gets stuck somewhere.

[image: OS X Right Arrow cursor]

Comment: Confirmed.  I just replicated the same thing on my system.

Comment: That should be it. :)